# Fedora 28 - random keyboard lag

Tags: linux, fedora, freeze, lag

I have recently installed Fedora on my new Dell Vostro 5471 laptop. EDIT: "This is the configuration with the AMD Radeon 530 Graphics card. Here is the full list of components: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OtwPfBbUkxggWvyxlyryaOe2nrYGbXJ9"

The installation froze at configuring user settings, so after 2 hours I have rebooted the laptop. Looked like everything was working fine, partitions were fine.

Only after reboot, when I was typing a weird lag happened. Cannot do nothing and when the lag ended the last character that was written before the lag, was written x-times (i.e. writeeeeeeeeeeee).

This problem does not repeat if the computer is up for maybe two/three hours.

Should I reinstall ? Maybe upgrade to 29 beta ? Is this a drivers problem ? Is there any program that will verify the integrity of my OS ?

EDIT: "After upgrading OS to Fedora 29, the problem seems to be gone, but still the cause is unknown"

Comment: Yeah, I'd definitely suggest trying the beta as the first approach. It's often the case that newer kernels support newer laptop hardware better.

Comment: Thanks, I will try the beta and I will let know if it fixed the issue

Comment: Does your Vostro have the Intel UHD620 Graphics, or the AMD Radeon™ 530? There are at least four models of the Vostro 5471, so please find out by entering your Service Tag at https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/vostro-14-5471-laptop/diagnose then once you know, please click on [edit] and add that info to your original question.

Comment: I have added the link to .csv file with full configuration. So it is the one with the Radeon 530 graphics.